# @controller instance variable in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, instance-variables

Just curious. How is the @controller instance variable inside the controller specs being instantiated? And where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is actually being done by  [ActionController::TestCase::Behavior#setup_controller_request_and_response](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a5013bb5af299db6bf97f67d4198220280717e80/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb#L486), which is wired up by [RSpec::Rails::SetupAndTeardownAdapter#setup](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/b17436f7aa5e52e3c19d7226752219915b650117/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb#L45-L55), which is included by [RSpec::Rails::RailsExampleGroup](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/b17436f7aa5e52e3c19d7226752219915b650117/lib/rspec/rails/example/rails_example_group.rb#L9) and used by [RSpec::Rails::ControllerExampleGroup](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/b17436f7aa5e52e3c19d7226752219915b650117/lib/rspec/rails/example/controller_example_group.rb#L8-L9). :)

`bundle open rspec-rails` is an easy way to start looking at how this stuff works.

HTH!